# replacing .innerText moves div position

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When the function **changeText()** is called the the **div** postion moves down for some reason

JS:

```
function changeText() {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerText = "string"
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" onmouseover="changeText()">
    <p>div 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: because you remove the paragraph tag. You are replacing the text of the div, not the paragraph in the div.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing all the content of the div with text. So you are removing the paragraph element. If you replace the content of the paragraph element it will not shift since the element remains.

```js
function changeText() {
    document.querySelector("#div1 p").innerText = "string"
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onmouseover="changeText()">
    <p>div 1</p>
</div>
```